# How can I edit the Visual Studio Code autocomplete?

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode shows single quotation for `className` when I write code in JSX:

`className=''`

but how can I edit it to:

`className=""`

Answer (score 1):

The setting

`Javascript > Preferences: Quote Style` set to `double` will do what you want.

I don't see a way to limit that setting to `jsx` files but that may not be a problem for you.

Comment: Yes, doesn't make problem... but I've obsession on quotation 